# spatio-temporal prediction with neural networks using decomposed time series data (SVD/ PCA) - how to predict with single time step?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, svd

**Edited for clarity and more information**

Let's say i have a data set containing observations at several sites for a couple of years (*24 hours) for a number of sites (e.g. 150). Sites are in rows, dates in columns (`y_train`):

```
sites   t1    t2   t3  ...  t363  t364  t365
1       4.7  4.9  5.0  ...   0.5   0.0   0.0
2       2.5  2.5  2.5  ...  -1.5  -2.2  -3.0
3       1.3  2.1  2.4  ...   0.5   0.1  -0.3
...
...
```

and another data set with location and altitude information (covariates, `X_train`) for those sites. Plus a data set containing sites with not-used measurements but with the location information (`X_test`) for testing purposes (`y_test`). Basically, some sort of spatio-temporal interpolation from one site to another location.

**Aim**: predict values at the `y_test` sites, `y_hat_test` where i only have location information but no measurements.

**Steps so far**:

- decomposing the observations using SVD to get some sort of residuals for every site.
- use the covariates as input to a neural network, the decomposed u-component and observations as target
- train the network which contains a recomposition to get the values "back" from the SVD
- predict using `X_test` as input for the network.

all the steps above work fine.

Testing the code on the subset of sites, thus using the information of the 20 sites as input to the pre-trained model, all works fine and i can predict for the "unknown" sites.

For testing I use 20 points/sites but the final version will have more >200000 points/sites.

Problem: i can't get my head over on how to best predict using the pre-trained model for a single time step,
i.e. i have my known sites but new observations / one new time step:

```
sites    t366
1         2.7 
2        -5.3
3       -10.2
...
...
```

My idea would be:

- apply SVD --> does this make sense at all for one time step?
- retrain the saved model using the single time step
- predict and fetch the latest index

Now, this throws me some nice and fancy errors in the recomposing layer with some matmul shape problems. Not that it does surprise me a lot.

However, how to best predict here in some sort of online-mode?
e.g. every time i have a new observation, how can i predict the values at the sites without observations?

Comment: in general neural nets are designed to not really require feature engineering ie precomputing some dimensionality reductions. also for this kind of problem start with simple sklearn models, there are many classifiers you can implement with very few LOC (these are more suited to such small data volumes)

Comment: edit for more clarity. In the end I have way more than 200000 sites. I'm not sure if this is a regression or classification problem here.